# Visual C++ 2010 Express using wrong toolset

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

My project has `Project > Properties > General > Platform Toolset` set to v100, however when I try to build I get

```
Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(511,5): error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v110) is   not installed or invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is selected.
```

I have searched the project file for `v110` and it is not in the file. I am coming from Linux and this Visual Studio stuff is being a big headache.

Is there another setting somewhere that I may be missing?

Edit:

I am getting this message when opening the project.
`C:\Users\Ryan\Downloads\CRYENGINE_Build_PC_v3_5_8_2310_freesdk\Code\CryEngine\CryAction\CryActionHeaders.vcxproj : warning  : Platform 'x64' referenced in the project file 'CryAction' cannot be found. Please make sure you have it installed under '%VCTargetsPath%\Platforms\x64'.`

Edit2:
I think I have found the problem. The $(PlatformToolset) macro is v110, im just not sure how to edit it yet.

Comment: Do you want to actually use that toolset (v100), or change the project settings to a toolset that exists?

Comment: I want to use v100 i don't have VS2012

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a long time ago. I concluded it was probably due to a bug in VS. I 'solved' it by creating a new project, and importing everything again.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you build the same project configuration as you are looking at.
At the top of the `General` page there are `Configuration > Debug/Release` and `Platform` (can be Win32/x64) comboboxes. Toolset setting can be different for each project configuration.

Comment: I only have Win32 Platform

Answer (score 0):

Open .vcproj in a text application (Notepad++), then find all instances of that declare the version.

Anything labeled v1xx or that has the word version in the tag (ie ) will be what needs to be changed to some form representative of the target version you are using.

If it has something like v141 and you want VS10 then it needs to be changed to v101.

Hope that helps.